# Facebook application: FB events work only for first time

Tags: facebook

I'm using the following code to subscribe to fb login and logout events.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) { 
             RefreshPageOnFBStatusChange(response); 
            }); 

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) { 
             RefreshPageOnFBStatusChange(response); 
            });

function RefreshPageOnFBStatusChange(response)
{
  alert(response.status);
}
```

I want to redirect users to different pages when they are logged in or logged out. The function I'm using here gets called only during the actual page load, and never after that. I have a fb-like, fb-share and live stream plugin on a page. When I login and logout of live stream, nothing happens. Help!

Comment: What happens if i set status=false in fb.init?

Answer (score 1):

Please modify your question and provide all FB-related code.
This may answer you question:
[Facebook FB.Event.subscribe event does not fire:(](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043960/facebook-fb-event-subscribe-event-does-not-fire)

Answer (score 0):

For User Status you can use if(FB._userStatus == "connected"){} to check user is login or not And for Logout & login you can use following simple code 
`FB.logout(function(response) {                                          window.location = redriect_uri;
});`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like these events don't fire when you use the live chat plugin because it has its own way of handling the login and logout. What I had to do to solve this problem was to set a timeout of 5 seconds and call a javascript function that did a FB.GetLoginStatus, and based on what it was I would refresh the page. Not the best way of doing it, but I was left with no choice.